# Changing a HTTP Header Name using a policy

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

**My Scenario:** I am using API Management to front a logic app that is going to represent my on boarding process which involves calling my security service.  To the outside world I want the consumer to pass me the user credential inside the Authorization Header.

**My Problem Part 1:** Logic Apps does not accept a Request with an Authorization Header

**My Idea:** Use a policy inside API Management to change the name of Authorization Header e.g. User-Agent which can be accepted by Logic Apps

**My Problem Part 2:** I cannot find anything that will simply allow me to change the name, loads on changing values but not the name.  I have even tried deleting the  Authorization Header inside Inbound Processing and recreating it with the new header name but you cannot save a policy that uses a value from a deleted property.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290489

Comment: Two completely different problem and definitely not a duplicate if you read the detail

Comment: Sorry about that. At the time of writing they did look identical. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new header first, and removing source one later:

```
<set-header name="X-Authorization" exist-action="override">
    <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", ""))</value>
<set-header>
<set-header name="Authorization" exist-action="delete" />
```

Comment: @TodaysRainTomorrowsWhisky, if that doesn't work. Please post the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your Response Vitaliy, I found another way of doing this which doesn't involve LogicApps so the problem went away but the error occurred when you tried to save the policy, it was stating you cannot save a policy that uses a value from a deleted property.